# Did Professor X ever marry someone?

Tags: character, x-men-cinematic-universe, x-men-apocalypse, x-men-first-class

In the original trilogy, there was not any mention about if Professor X was married to someone. However, while I was watching **X-Men First Class**, it seemed that Moira MacTaggert might be the one who Professor X will marry. But when he erased her memories, that assumption just went wrong. Recently, I watched **X-Men Apocalypse** and in this movie, he returns her memories. While watching this movie, it was clear that he has feelings for her and perhaps, he will marry her. However, the movie ended without clearing that up.

So, my question is, did Professor X marry someone? Is there any reference that he will marry Moira MacTaggert?

**NOTE:**

I am asking if Prof X got married in any medium including comics etc. It is hinted in the new X Men movie, but it's not clear.

Comment: He marries Moira, in some comics. Here is an article talking about that www.bleedingcool.com/2014/07/30/so-who-exactly-is-charles-xaviers-widow-spoilers/ . In other ones he marries a girl (I can't remember the girl) and they have a kid, called legion (David Charles Haller). I've read a lot of comics where moira marries a politician even she is in love with Charles.

Comment: How could we even know? After DoFP everything is a fair deal as past films are not much of canon. But for now its pure speculation and nothing else

Comment: Historically, Xavier has had a long standing mutual but unfulfilled attraction to Moira (One version has had them engaged but never married), a raging crush on his student Jean (ew, squick) that at one point lead to the creation of the most murderous villain in X-Men history (Onslaught), and an alien queen as a lover (The Shi'ar Lilandra). Those are the biggest one.

Comment: @AJ I'm not 100% clear: are you asking about what happened or was hinted at in the Fox movies only? Or are you asking if Prof X got married in any *other* medium (e.g. the comics, TV cartoons, etc?)

Comment: @KutuluMike I am asking if Prof X got married in any other medium including comics etc. It is hinted in the new X Men movie, but it's not clear. If you have any details, please reopen the question and add these as answer.

Comment: @AJ this question seems to me out of scope of this site.

Comment: @Panther Please explain in what aspects it appears to be out of scope of this site. This question is about a plot in the movie that can be answered by referencing other medium as well. We have done that on many occasions.

Comment: Answer has to come completely from different medium as it is not cleared any where in movie.

Comment: @Panther Well, the answer can include both references to movie and comics and the current answer does that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like any decades long comic, or story with multiple versions in multiple media, there is always the chance that someone gets married then it gets undone/someone dies/etc. Including Xavier. That said, he's pretty much eternally a bachelor. He has had three major romantic interests:

1. A very squick-y interest in Jean Grey. This was brought up when Xavier became one of the most murder-y villains in X-Men history, Onslaught, in the 90s, and back in the 2000's Ultimate X-Men.

[image]

Considering movie Xavier is in his 50s and Jean is now 16-ish, this will never ever happen on screen.

2. Lilandra Neramani, queen of the Shi'ar. The Shi'ar are a galaxy empire, and in the comics they are the sworn enemies of the Kree (as seen in the Guardians of the Galaxy movie). At one point he fakes his death so that he could be her consort. He never becomes king, just lovers.

[image]

She showed up in the 90's "The X-Men" cartoon, during the Dark Phoenix Saga. Which is the rumored topic of the next X-Men movie, now that *[All is Revealed](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/53661/why-did-apocalypse-say-this)*.

[image]

3. Moira MacTaggart. An intense mutual attraction, these two were at one point engaged, only for Moira to break it off to go back with her abusive ex.

[image]

Xavier and Moira have maintained a very professional relationship, both keeping their emotions in check, in the comics and cartoon. In the comics, she eventually dies after being attacked by Mystique. She and Xavier hook up once more before she dies. Yep.

### In the movies, the plan as far as we know, is only to keep the Xavier and Moira relationship just [barely on the top.](http://www.michaelfassbender.org/introsebyrne.html)

> Movieline: Oh, yes. Moira and Xavier have a famous romantic relationship in the comics. How much of that relationship will we get to see?
>
> Rose Bryne: I think it's more of a hint than a full painting, or whatever the metaphor might be. [Laughs] But there's definitely a flirtation and an affection; they're allies, so from the start they're there for each other.

The recent movie does the same, with just a kiss and some knowing looks.

Comment: I think Gabrielle Haller should be mentioned too as she had his child.

Answer (score 1):

In the current timeline(s) of the former FOX *X-Men* films, **No**.

[image: LEGION]

But in the TV series [*Legion*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legion_(TV_series)), which features Professor X's and Gabrielle Haller's son, David Haller, **yes**. Charles was married to Gabrielle. In season 3 Charles and Gabrielle are featured apart of time travel story...

[image: Charles Gabrielle]

> Landgraf stated, in January 2016, **that the series would be set in a
>   universe parallel to the X-Men films** where "the US government is in
>   the early days of being aware that something called mutants exist but
>   the public is not". He felt it was unlikely that characters would
>   cross over between the show and films, but noted that this could
>   change between then and the premiere of the series.[57] That July, an
>   article on Marvel.com referred to Legion as one of several characters
>   joining the Marvel Cinematic Universe (MCU), **suggesting that Legion
>   would be set in that shared universe** like Marvel Television's other
>   series.[83] The next month, Singer said that Legion had actually been
>   **designed to fit into the X-Men universe, but also to stand alone**, so
>   "you wouldn't have to label" the relationship between the series and
>   the films. He teased plans to have the series "relate to future X-Men
>   movies".

*Legion* is still considered apart of FOX's continuity, but in all honesty, it exist in it's own timeline(s) and only references both the films and comics lightly with no evidence of a *direct connection* to the films.

But, and as the other answer(s) suggest, because *X-Men* in both films, TV Series, and/or comics include other timelines and/or parallel universes, there are instances where some version of Charles has been married.