# How did (young) Jean exactly defeat Apocalypse?

Tags: plot-explanation, x-men-cinematic-universe, x-men-apocalypse

In *X-Men: Apocalypse* (2016) at final battle, Jean saved the day. We saw that she screamed and unleashed her powers, as a phoenix-lookalike aura around her and Apocalypse lost it.

She didn't strike it directly at him, for example like (young) Storm hit him with thunder bolts to stop him from escape. All I saw (if I don't miss anything) her powers radiated around and kind of locked him in his tracks.

How did it work? And why did it not effect to all people around her?

Comment: Related: [Why does the healing ability not help Subah Nur?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/56327/27264)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The last fighting sequence  with the Villain, professor x actually enters the mind of him and this is where the action occurs.While Professor x was in the brink of defeat, he calls Jean for help.Jean posses power that can challenge Professor in every way(this was seen in X-men 3 ,where professor says he locked away some of the powers of Jean).In the Apocalypse, she was able to release this power.As we all say our mind is everything,Apocalypse mind was messed up by Jean.Hence, Jean was affecting only his mind not every one else.This is why he was struggling to fight back and tried to escape through the portal.But this was again prevented by our Heroes.

Answer (score 1):

All of Jean Grey's powers derive from her raw psychic ability (telekinesis, telepathy etc) and there's reasonable evidence in the X-Men Cinematic Universe that her raw power level in this regard completely outstrips *everybody* (including Xavier) when it is allowed to operate unrestrained.

As we see in *X-Men: The Last Stand* she can wield telekinetic forces strong enough to disintegrate people, tanks etc. with very little difficulty, reach out telepathically across vast distances without the aid of Cerebro (such as when she "calls" to Cyclops from Alkali Lake)

Her attack on Apocalypse is primarily a *psychic* one - she enters Xavier's mind (where he is mentally fighting Apocalypse) in order to help and starts attacking him psychicly herself, it is this psychic onslaught that distracts/weakens Apocalypse enough to allow the others (Storm etc) to attack his physical form directly.

The whole thing where Jean walks out of the window, levitates there and gives off the Phoenix-shaped aura of fire is primarily to show the viewer that Jean is throwing around *a lot* of power and because, well it looks *cool*.

Comment: While this answer at least looks better then earlier, it's still incorrect. She unlock access to Phoenix Power. I wonder why you speculated and not just googled...